# How to properly write RabbitMQ Publisher on Java?

Tags: java, queue, rabbitmq, client, producer-consumer

Do we need to create individual channels for each thread or use the same channel for all threads? Also the same question about connection. Do we need to use different connections for each thread or a single connection?
What is the difference when we use one channel across all threads and individual channels for each thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Connection**:

According to the java doc (https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.6.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.6.5/):

Current implementations are thread-safe for code at the client API level, and in fact thread-safe internally except for code within RPC calls.

**Channel**:

According to the doc (https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html):

Channel instances must not be shared between threads. Applications should prefer using a Channel per thread instead of sharing the same Channel across multiple threads. While some operations on channels are safe to invoke concurrently, some are not and will result in incorrect frame interleaving on the wire. Sharing channels between threads will also interfere with * Publisher Confirms.